# Question based on circular permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Consider 21 different pearls on a necklace. The number of ways can the pearls be placed in on this necklace such that 3 specific pearls always remain together is?

Using the string method, I got the final answer as $(6)(18!)$, but given answer is $(3)(18!)$.

This brings me to my question. The only way $(3)(18!)$ can be the answer of clockwise and counterclockwise arrangements are taken as same.
How do we make the distinction between the two cases where circular arrangements matter and where they don’t matter.

Comment: Counter-clockwise rotations by $k$ spaces are just clockwise rotations by $n-k$ spaces.  What is probably happening here is that the objects are being treated as combinatorial [bracelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) instead of as necklaces where we also consider reflections of the object to be equivalent.  This is somewhat implied by the fact that the necklace has pearls/beads which generally do not matter which part of the pearl is out-facing.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about terminology, or perhaps about different counting for two cases.  Many authors use the phrase [necklace problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) for the situation that reflection (reversing clockwise to counterclockwise) is *not* considered as equivalent,  and *bracelet problem* for situations when reflection is allowed in the scope of equivalent arrangements.   Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @JMoravitz I get that it doesn’t really matter which pearl is outpacing, but in round table problems, we consider clockwise and counterclockwise to be separate cases

Comment: @hardmath yes. How do we differentiate between necklace and bracelet problems?